# How to check if a set is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal

Hi guys Im stuck on a question.

Given $\{u,v,w\}$ orthonormal set, prove that $\{u+2v+w,u-v+w,u-w\}$ is an orthogonal set.
I know that im supposed to prove

$$\langle u+2v+w,u-v+w\rangle=0$$
$$\langle u+2v+w,u-w\rangle = 0$$
$$\langle u-v+w,u-w\rangle= 0$$

but I have no idea on how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of orthogonal/orthonormal "group"? What you mean is apparently orthogonal/orthonormal "set", given what you are supposed to prove.

Comment: Hi Julien, sorry missed you comment, I did mean a set. edited.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $$\langle x+y,z\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle+\langle y,x\rangle$$
that is $$(x+y)\cdot z=x\cdot z+y\cdot z$$

You know that $$\langle u,v\rangle =\langle u,w\rangle =\langle w,v\rangle =0$$

$$\langle v,v\rangle =\langle u,u\rangle = \langle w,w\rangle =1$$

**EXAMPLE**

$$\begin{align}
  \langle u - v + w,u - w\rangle  &= \langle u - v,u - w\rangle  + \langle w,u - w\rangle  \\ 
   &= \langle u,u - w\rangle  + \langle  - v,u - w\rangle  + \langle w,u\rangle  + \langle w, - w\rangle  \\
   &= \langle u,u\rangle  + \langle u, - w\rangle  + \langle  - v, - w\rangle  + \langle  - v,u\rangle  + \langle w,u\rangle  + \langle w, - w\rangle  \\
   &= \langle u,u\rangle  - \langle u,w\rangle  + \langle v,w\rangle  - \langle v,u\rangle  + \langle w,u\rangle  - \langle w,w\rangle  \\
   &= 1 - 0 + 0 - 0 + 0 - 1 = 0 \end{align}$$

One can write things more concisely, of course $$\left( {u - v + w} \right)\cdot \left( {u - w} \right) = {u\cdot u} - u\cdot v + w\cdot u - w\cdot u + v\cdot w - {w \cdot w} = 1 - 1 = 0$$

You can do the same for the others. $$(u + 2v + w)\cdot(u - w) = {u^2} + 2v\cdot u + w\cdot u - w\cdot u - 2v\cdot w - {w\cdot w} = 1 - 1 = 0$$

$$\begin{align}(u + 2v + w)\cdot(u - v + w) &=u\cdot u + 2v\cdot u + w\cdot u - u\cdot v \\& - \;\;2{v\cdot v} - v\cdot w + w\cdot u \\&+\;\;2v\cdot w + {w\cdot w} \\&= 1 - 2 + 1 = 0\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi peter thanks! My problem is that Im not sure how to use properties, can you please show me how to use the properties for the first step of u+2v+w, what am I supposed to do with the "2v"?

Comment: @gogo Maybe now it is clearer?

Comment: @gogo We use the "distributive" property over and over again. It is just like multiplying numbers, really.

Comment: Hi Peter, when I want to use this property ⟨x+y,z⟩=⟨x,z⟩+⟨y,x⟩ on <u+2v+w,u-w> I got 2 "+", do I decide which one is "x" and which is "y" (in the property), x=u+2v y=w?

Comment: @gogo Well, you can pick the one you like. For example, $$(u+2v+w)\cdot(u-v)=(u+2v)\cdot(u-w)+w\cdot(u-v)$$ $$(u+2v+w)\cdot(u-v)=u\cdot(u-w)+(2v+w)\cdot(u-v)$$

Comment: Thanks! I was really confused since our course-book is very unclear. You really made it simple (:

Comment: @gogo Could you address what julien is asking you in the comments?

Comment: @gogo I am glad this helped. If so, you may accept the answer using the checkmark.